# Grill used for neveilot

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, kashering-kosherization, non-kosher-species

Assuming I have a grill and someone I know uses it, without my permission, to cook meat from a neveilah (or perhaps not, but kosher species without certification). What is the status of the grill and how difficult is it to kasher without specialised equipment?

Comment: Heat it up to 1000F degrees for a bit.

Comment: @DoubleAA How can it get that high? the thermostat only goes up to 550̊ f, so how would I tell?

Comment: But seriously, none of us know what your grill looks like. Does it have plastic pieces? Porcelain pieces? How hot can it usually get? How is anyone supposed to answer this question?

Comment: If you want to kasher it, see [here](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-kashering.htm) and [here](http://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/ou-kosher-presents-the-top-consumer-questions-received-for-the-summer/).

Comment: @DoubleAA the grate is stainless steel, the the rest of the body is metal, the outside has enamel, however there is none on the cooking surface.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt That sounds oddly non-hypothetical.

Comment: That's the average one I've seen in my neighbourhood.

Comment: You can always use a giant magnifying glass. When the sunlight goes through it, I think that will get up to 1,000 deg. I assume you mean Farenheit :-) How would you tell? WHo says that anyone else has to know what you're doing? ;-) ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The Shulchan Arukh rules (OC 451:4) that a vessels used on a fire like a skewer or grill need to be heated up until sparks come off of them in order to kasher them. My understanding is that this is about 1000 degrees Fahrenheit or when it [glows red](http://www.hearth.com/talk/wiki/know-temperature-when-metal-glows-red/). If it is earthenware you'd have to refire it in a kiln (ibid. :1). I can't comment about the specifics of any case, so practically you should CYLOR about the setup and different parts of any particular grill.

Comment: Rabbi Shimon Eider attests that metal nowadays will not spark due to the advanced purification processes of metal making nowadays, there are no impuritie to burn off as sparks.

Comment: @user6591 Could be. I don't suspect that would change the required temperature at all.

Comment: Same here. But some people wait wait around till they see sparks, and its just not gonna happen. Kinda like shiduchim.

Comment: @DoubleAA what does "OC" stand for ?

Comment: @CodyBugstein "Orach Chayim" which is one of the four sections of [Shulchan Arukh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch#Structure)

Comment: @DoubleAA Based on the link you shared, shouldn't this type of Halacha be in "Yorea Dea" which is supposed to deal with Kashrut?

Comment: @CodyBugstein Indeed, but many of the rules about Kashering vessels ended up in the laws of Pesach along with the discussions of how to clean and purge from Chametz (Yoreh Deah 121:3 actually says "See what I wrote in the laws of Pesach"). Good question!

Comment: "The Rambam put everything in order, and the Shulchan Aruch moved everything out of order" -- Rabbi Hershel Schachter, shlit"a.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're only talking about the grill proper, i.e. the metal grid the meat rests on, you would need to do libun. The required temperatures can be reached with a propane torch. YMMV as to whether or not a propane torch counts as special equipment.