# Must one use a separate grill for meat and fish?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, health-safety-shmira, fish

As there is a prohibition of mixing meat with fish because of *sakana* ("danger"), I assume that if one has a small grill, one cannot grill meat and then grill fish (or vice versa) without cleaning the grill in between. However, let's say the grill has a large surface area such that a piece of meat and a piece of fish can be grilled in separate areas of the grill, and the two don't touch each other.

Can one cook the two items this way? Or are they still considered "mixed" by the fact that they are sharing the same grill and the same flame? Is there a problem with meat and fish juices dripping into the coal / rock grill area where the flame is?

Comment: partially related - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44929/5275

Comment: @DanF You're avoiding my point. Did you read the Rama there? You keep citing sources about grilling meat and fish together and pretending they don't talk about grilling meat and fish together!

Comment: Do poskim who rule that fish and meat be eaten together in some or all cases count as an answer?

Comment: @mevaqesh Not really. I wouldn't be asking this question, then. I am aware that there are opinions that say this is no longer a sakana, and thus eating fish and meat together is not a problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA Took me a while to respond. I got it. I edited the link after the answer, which, of course, makes it seem as if the answer is already in my own question! I'm going to add this to the answer. If that still doesn't make sense, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [OU article](https://oukosher.org/faqs/can-a-bbq-be-used-for-both-meat-and-fish/) as well as par. 8d in this [Star K article](http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/706/meat-and-dairy-a-kosher-consumers-handbook/), separate grill racks must be used or the fish must be wrapped in foil. They don't seem to distinguish the size of the grill rack.

[Yoreh De'ah 116:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.116.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) indicates that one cannot roast fish and meat together because of the smells transmitted between the two items.

Comment: The OU article says that the reason to ue a different rack is that "it is extremely difficult to clean a grill". That seems at first glance to mean that, if one could clean it, then cleaning it would suffice and kashering would not be necessary. (That's at first glance; I'm not saying it's true.) And that *might* imply that the only issue is tangible mixing substances, not absorbed tastes. And that would seem to imply that your case of a large grill with meat on one end and fish on the other would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @msh210 Your reasoning sounds .... reasonable (for lack of a better word). Up for discussion. Perhaps, I can ask a mashgiach in my neighborhood. I don't think he's affiliated with either the OU or Star-K :-0