# Can one cook meat and fish dishes at the same time in the same oven?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, meat, fish

The gemara in [Pesachim 76b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.76b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) forbids one from cooking meat and fish together because of danger.

But **can one cook meat and fish dishes separately at the same time in the same oven?** There can be a need to do this when preparing lots of food at the same time, e.g., before a 2-day holiday.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71786/759

Answer (score 4):

Many halachic decisors permit cooking meat and fish dishes simultaneously provided at least one of them is covered ([SA YD 108:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.108.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). After the fact, it is permitted to eat the food even if not covered ([Rema on SA YD 116:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.116.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

[DailyHalacha](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1657) writes

> When meat and fish are cooked together in a closed area, the steam
> produced by one is absorbed by the other. Therefore, one should avoid
> cooking meat and fish together in an oven or closed grill, unless the
> fish or the meat is covered, such as with aluminum foil and the like,
> so that it is shielded from the steam produced by the other.
> Nevertheless, after the fact, if one did cook fish and meat together
> in an oven without covering one of them, they are permissible for
> consumption.

[dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2011/01/30/meat-and-fish-in-same-oven/) brings the following

> Although the Gemara (Pesachim 76b) does imply that it would a problem,
> even bedieved, to cook meat and fish together in the same oven, the
> fact that this halachah is not ruled by Rif or Rambam has led poskim
> to be lenient. Although we continue to be careful not to eat fish and
> meat together, many authorities are lenient concerning fish or meat
> that absorbed the taste (alone) of the other.
>
> For lenient opinions, see: Issur Ve’heter 39:25, as cited in Rema,
> Yoreh De’ah 116; Shach, Yoreh De’ah 116:1; Taz, YD 95:3; Darchei
> Teshuvah 116:16 (quoting from several authorities); Ha’elef Lecha
> Shlomo 312. For more stringent opinions, see Peri Chadash (116:4);
> Peri Toar (116:3); Chochmas Adam (68:1).
>
> Lechatchilah, one should not cook meat and fish [uncovered] in the same oven, but
> bedieved, one may rely on the lenient opinions.

R Yitzhak Yaacov Fuchs writes (in his book Hakashrut, p. 418)

> *Lchatchilah*, it is forbidden to put meat and fish together in the same baking compartment in the oven even though each one is in a separate baking utensil. It would be permissible if one of the baking utensils was
> covered entirely in a complete manner (wrapped all around and
> hermetically closed). *Bdieved* [after the fact] if not fat or juices
> dropped from one utensil to the other it is permissible to eat both
> foods (Aruch Hashulchan YD 116:10)

R Ari Enkin [summarizes](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/dalet-amot-of-halacha/fish-and-meat/)

> This would logically extend to restrict baking dishes with these two
> types of foods in the oven at the same time, unless both pots are well
> covered, lest any tastes, via the steam, spread from one to the other.

See also [here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/newsletterArticle.asp?lang=en&pageid=4&cat=7&newsletter=916&article=3512) at length from Eretz Hemda which concludes

> while it is halachically safer to not roast meat and fish uncovered in
> the same oven, it seems reasonable to do so in a regular, large oven
> when there is a need

Comment: "many authorities are lenient concerning fish or meat that absorbed the taste (alone) of the other" Indeed almost no one has separate pots for cooking fish

Comment: "halachically safer" what does this mean?

Comment: @DoubleAA interestingly I saw now that the [Tur 116:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Yoreh_Deah.116.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) mentions that some have the custom to have fish-specific dishes (ויש מחמירין בדבר לייחד לדגים כלים לבד). The Beit Yosef and SA don't pick it up. I leave it here for reference

Answer (score 0):

Kitzer Shulchan Aruch Siman 33:1

> One should not roast meat together with fish in one oven if the oven is small, unless one of them is covered, [for otherwise the aroma of one gives flavor to the other.]

See Rama, Yoreh Deah 116:2 (see also Taz and Shach there)

> But in out ovens that are large, this is no need to be concerned.

The footnote here says that the author is speaking of ovens in his day and a rabbinic authority should be consulted to be determine whether one's oven is large in this respect.

In conclusion, one of the dishes needs to be covered, unless according to a rabbinic authority, your oven is large.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers offered, take the tact that it is a granted that it is contemporaneously forbidden to eat meat and fish together. It is worth noting that this assumption is not universal.

There are today Ashkenazim and Sefaradim that understand there to be no prohibition extant and therefore do not refrain from eating meat/fish. And all the more so would certainly not refrain from cooking them in the same oven.

For a great analysis of this issue, see [R. Zekharyah Zaramati's responsum here](http://www.toratemet.net/image/users/21292/ftp/my_files/wiki/%D7%93%D7%92%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%92%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A8-%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99%27%D7%94%20%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99.pdf?id=24830382).

Comment: Seems more like a comment as the question is pretty clearly asking according to the other (more common) view.

Comment: @DoubleAA if it is only seeking one particular subview, then that should be specified in the OP. Otherwise, IMHO this is a legitimate answer (i.e. that yes, cooking meat/fish together in the same oven at the same time is permitted).

Comment: How explicit does an OP need to be?? "Is corn forbidden as kitniyot?" "Rav Yosef Karo rules kitniyot are permitted and that would include corn."

Comment: IMHO: If seeking answers specific to those that customarily refrain from it, that would be better worded as "According to those whose custom it is to forbid kitniyot, does corn fall within its purview?" (or something to that effect) As worded, it would indeed appropriately be open to that type of answer.

Comment: That's a highly unreasonable standard. Not everyone even knows certain things which are an essential to the question are subject to dispute. How do you expect someone to write a question? "According to positions that view halacha as binding, can I, according to those who think I'm not a slave, eat food, according to those who view things consumed as food, on saturday, according to those who view shabbat on saturday?"

Comment: Teaching people about other variant opinions is surely a worthwhile use of a comment. But it doesn't answer what the person himself wanted to know.

Comment: How would I expect a more narrowly focused question to be composed? I addressed that above with an example. It seems to me that unless an OP tailors his question to a specific subset of answer types, then it is naturally open to a wider array of answers. Such is one of the main benefits of boards such as these, I might add. I do not see anything in the MiYodeya rules/guidelines that contraindicates my tact here.

Comment: Is your answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16354/what-blessing-does-one-make-on-a-solar-eclipse/16357#16357) substantially different than mine here? The OP appears to take it for granted that a blessing is appropriate, and indeed there are decisors that endorse the recitation of a blessing. Yet your answer focuses contrarily on the perspective of those that either forbid or place doubt on the recitation of a blessing. Would your answer there have been better off as a comment?

Comment: Indeed mine is quite substantially different. Rejecting an assumption is a great way to answer a question IF it's indeed an invalid premise. Moreover the assumption you claim to be in the question isn't actually there.

Comment: The assumption in the question is quite plainly there. He intends to recite a blessing on the event and wants to know which. He did not ask for sources that oppose the recitation of a blessing. As for rejecting an assumption, that is quite clearly what I offer here... as for whether a premise is valid or not, that is obviously open to interpretation and tradition. It seems to me that this is a case of whats good for the goose is good for the gander. Removing this answer would be the implementation of a double standard wherein one rule applies to a mod, and another to other users.

Comment: That's complete balderdash and I will not stand for it. What assumptions are valid is not even remotely debatable here, even if there may be some edge cases elsewhere. Nothing to do with geese or ducks. You don't have to like the other side to know it exists. There is no double standard here at all and I resent the implication that I would do such a thing. Showing that this technically violates no rules may save it from deletion but that doesn't save it from being an abuse of the system.

Comment: I wish to point out that we are bid to "avoid extended discussions in comments." You can sit or stand as you please. I stand by my assertion that a double standard would be at play here if this is removed. What you see as "abuse" I see as precisely that the system is meant to facilitate.

Comment: Oh don't worry I will follow the rules no matter what you think. (And indeed there actually are rules about this issue that you have been unaware of https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2179/759 ) The only thing for you to do is consider that I resent the accusation.

Comment: The meta seeks to raise and discuss these issues. The post you reference has the discussion tag, i.e. intended to discuss an issue in order to facilitate community consensus. Based on the post, was there ever any formal rule change or policy issued on the matter? To my observation there was not. If there was, I would be glad to read it. If not, then no there actually are not rules about this particular issue (contrary to your assertion). As for following rules and guidelines, I once again wish to remind you that we are bid to "avoid extended discussion in comments."

Comment: Is there any mainstream posek or community that allows eating meat and fish together? I never heard of that until you wrote this

Comment: @mbloch I don't know about the qualifier "mainstream" (easily run into no true scotsman issues there), but as far as poseqim that permit: R. Dov Lior (Chief Rabbi of Hebron) permits it, and R. Yisroel Chait (Rosh Yeshivah of YBT in Far Rockaway) permits it. Community-wise I know that there are people in their respective communities that so conduct themselves. I can also report anecdotally that I have met Baghdadi and Moroccan Jews with a mesorah to not refrain from it.

Comment: @Deuteronomy I checked this and you are correct re R Dov Lior who bases himself on the Magen Avraham OC 173:2. But at least in Israel he is considered an extreme opinion not to be relied upon in practice. I leave this here for myself more than to convince you :->

Comment: @mbloch I guess by that same token the MA is "extreme" and the Rambam גדול הרופאים (and many other Rishonim) that altogether ignore this concern are as well  As for whether a particular view is to be relied upon in practice, that all depends on your particular halakhic epistemology 