# Can one use a gas grill for both meat and dairy (i.e. pizza)?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk

Can a meat grill be used to cook dairy, like pizza? If so, what must one do to prepare it for the dairy?

Comment: Similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44929/can-one-use-a-gas-grill-for-both-meat-and-dairy-with-lots-of-other-caveats

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7496

Comment: Welcome to MY. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 1):

The STAR-K [writes](https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/706/meat-and-dairy-a-kosher-consumers-handbook/#f6)

> One may not heat any fleishig product in a dairy toaster or toaster
>   oven (unless it is double wrapped in foil). One may not grill dairy
>   (or fish) on a fleishig grill unless the food is double wrapped in
>   foil.

Regarding the second part of your question, the OU [explains](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/frequently-asked-summer-questions/) how to kasher from a ***non-kosher*** grill

> Since food is roasted directly on the grill, the grate must be heated
>   until it glows (libun gomur) to be properly kashered. This can be done
>   either with a blowtorch (which should only be used by qualified and
>   experienced individuals) or by sandwiching the grates between charcoal
>   briquettes and setting them on fire. In addition, if the grill has a
>   hood, the empty gas grill cavity must be kashered by cleaning, closing
>   the hood and setting it to the highest setting for one hour (libun
>   kal).  Alternatively, one may replace the grates and kasher only the
>   grill cavity as explained above.

Nonetheless, kashering between meat and dairy isn't simple. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7499/13811) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: I wonder why, though. Assuming no lid on the grill, I'd think a double layer of foil beneath the food should suffice sans wrapping.

Comment: Now this answer is straight up misleading. A non kosher grill is not the same as a kosher grill of the wrong gender.

Comment: Your linked post says "If you want to kasher using libun you can do so at any time, even for Ashkenazim" so that shouldn't be an issue. Why have you obfuscated the fact that all answers to that post would allow this transition Lekhatchila?